# How to implement security for my Microservices with Spring?

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, spring-cloud, microservices, spring-cloud-netflix

We have one monolithic application having more than 10 services like user management, fleet booking, feedback and etc developed on spring rest.

We want to migrate to Microservices(Spring Boot + Cloud + Netflix OSS).

Below are my questions :
How can we implement security for all our rest services (with own user database)?
How to implement api gateway from security stand point ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit wide question to be asked, but here is a solution from my experience. 
If you have your own user/pass db then apply spring security, include spring security in every micro service, spring security in each one will query the DB that you have for user/pass and the session, when user authenticates. This way all services will be secured.

Oauth2 is another solution

Check this links too: 
https://spring.io/blog/2015/10/19/springone2gx-2015-replay-securing-microservices-with-spring-cloud-security

https://spring.io/blog/2014/11/07/webinar-replay-security-for-microservices-with-spring-and-oauth2

Comment: Thanks Adelin for quick response. Actually I am looking for some security token to be passed for every services. Like my own auth service will give the token and for subsequesnt rest call I will pass the token. My question is how to do it ?

Comment: I think Oauth is the answer, oauth works in token ...